# write a prog that inputs an integer 0-999 and then prints if the integer entered is a 1/2/3 digit number

Tags: python, string

```
a=int(input("enter a number:"))
for i in range(0,999):
   if (a\<10):
     print('''single digit number''')
   elif (a\>10 and a\<100):
     print("double digit number")
   elif (a\>100 and a\<=999):
     print(f"{a} is triple digit number")
```

Can anyone please explain me why it's output is iterating many times?

Comment: (1) The shown code contains backslashes which shouldn't be there. (2) You have a for-loop that runs thousand times containing some print calls.

Comment: `for i in range(0,999):` ...

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). See also [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341)

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `for i in range(0,999):`, what do you think this means? Do you see how this relates to the problem described?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code asks the user for a number. Then, it 999 times prints the amount of digits in that number. I assume you didn't want to make this iteration at all (so you should just remove the `for` loop to avoid it printing 999 times).

The following code should do the desired action - only printing the amount of digits once (assuming the number is in the range 1-999, and does nothing otherwise.

```py
a = int(input("Enter a number:"))

if 0 < a < 10:
    print(f"{a} is a single digit number")
elif 10 <= a < 100:
    print(f"{a} is a double digit number")
elif 100 <= a < 1000:
    print(f"{a} is a triple digit number")
```

Comment: `amount_digits = len(str(a))`

Comment: That’s a lot easier - I made it too complicated, lol.

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not attempt to answer questions that should be closed instead.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Your link shows a list of 5 types of questions that shouldn’t be answered - none of which apply here. The only thing from the guide that applies here is “There’s always a real human being on the other end ... however misguided they may appear to be,” hence my polite and helpful answer. Furthermore, the error in the question was not caused by typos nor is impossible to reproduce, so the current closing reason is also incorrect.